# App Engine - Remove file change detection from dev_appserver log

Tags: google-app-engine

In a recent SDK update, it seems that Google has added a INFO level log into the dev_appserver that prints out each and every time a file change is detected.

This, in my opinion, just clutters up the log with information I already know thus I don't want it to be printed out on my console.

```
INFO     2014-11-27 09:52:43,876 module.py:391] [default] Detected file changes:
  /Users/michael/app/templates/home
  /Users/michael/app/templates/home/index.html
```

Is there any way to remove these lines from the log? Since this is a INFO level log, I can't really remove the INFO from the log_level as other INFO logs come in handy many times...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would also like to see an answer for this.

Comment: It drives me bonkers. I even tried changing the --log_level and it had no effect.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's now an issue on the App Engine issue tracker. Vote it up for quicker resolution.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11662

Comment: Where is the link to the issue on the issue tracker?

Comment: Just fixed my answer. I pasted a link to this question in the issue and meant to paste the issue link here, but accidentally self-linked this question to itself. :)

Comment: You may want to star this one as well, IMHO even more useful: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9300

Answer (score 2):

This issue started to bug me also, so here's my quick-fix until devs find more permanent solution:

in `path-to-SDK\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py` comment out lines 424-426.

```
424 # logging.info(
425 #     '[%s] Detected file changes:\n  %s', self.name,
426 #     '\n  '.join(sorted(file_changes)))
```

Just have to remember to do it again when the build changes, if they don't fix it. (I'm working with 1.9.20 atm) (:

Comment: This just changes the logs. The file is still reloaded.

Comment: Couple of lines before that line is:
file_changes = self._get_file_changes(timeout)

Change it to:
file_changes = {change for change in self._get_file_changes(timeout) if not change.startswith('.git') and not change.startswith('.idea')}

Answer (score 0):

As [Derek Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691542/derek-perkins) pointed out, this was sent to the [App Engine Issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11662). Since I had the same problem I starred the issue. I was happily surprised to see it was actually sent up to engineering and they updated the tracker today with a workaround. I rewrote parts of it and added a bit of formatting :)

**Root cause of the problem**

The main reason behind why every file in a project's folder is tracked is because the reload logic is naïve and has no way of knowing which files are actually being in use.

In the event that some data file contents are changed, but only loaded at module import time (for instance templates in some frameworks), it's difficult for the devserver to accurately detect such changes.

**Workaround for Git and Mercurial**

If you put your project folder anywhere but the root of your git repo, it will make all the `.git` files appear outside of your project's dir, so the changes to the files should not be seen and therefore shouldn't trigger a webserver reload. For instance build your project's structure this way :

```
myproject/ 
myproject/.git/ 
myproject/.gitignore 
myproject/myapp/ 
myproject/myapp/app.yaml 
myproject/README
```

Then run the devserver inside of myproject/myapp instead of "myproject".

There is also a mention that this has been tested on Git and Mercurial, but it won't work on CVS or SVN.